# Java ProcessBuilder not able to run Python script in Java

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

`null` from `bfr.readLine()`

However, there is no problem if I run the python file directly on terminal by firing:

> python C:/Machine_Learning/Text_Analysis/Ontology_based.py

The last line in my Python script is `>> print(data)`

The result of the following code is:

Running Python starts:

> First Line: null
>
> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

---

```
package text_clustering;

import java.io.*;

public class Similarity {

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            String pythonPath = "C:/Machine_Learning/Text_Analysis/Ontology_based.py";
            //String pythonExe = "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda/python.exe";
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", pythonPath);
            Process p = pb.start();
            
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            System.out.println("Running Python starts: " + line);
            line = bfr.readLine();
            System.out.println("First Line: " + line);
            while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Python Output: " + line);
                
                
            }

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }

}
```

Comment: You'd better grab the error stream as well and check what it's putting out as you may have an error situation. Alternatively you could combine the error stream with the input stream, and read that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels,THANKS! Sorry, I am a newbie in both Java and Python... so do u mean that in the Java code block, instead of catch Exception, I throw Exception? Many Thanks again!

Comment: No. Change your catch block though to `e.printStackTrace()` for more information, but that's a separate issue. I mean that you should capture the ErrorStream just as you do the InputStream. But easiest just to call `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` to redirect the error stream into the input stream.

Comment: hmmm, I added pb.redirectErrorStream(true) in the try{} block and e.printStackTrace() in the catch{} block... but it seems nothing chance? Am I missing something? would you mind showing an example please? Thanks so much

Comment: My recommendation was only to see if errors were occurring that you did not see. As long as you're redirecting the error stream immediately after creating your ProcessBuilder object, you're following my recommendations. Then something else might be wrong. How do you run your python script if you weren't using Java? Do you need to give the full path to python.exe?

Comment: This python script can be run with no problem on Terminal using command line: python scriptfile_path+scriptfile_name

Answer (score 3):

Usually when executing commands using **ProcessBuilder**, `PATH` variable is not taken into consideration. Your `python C:/Machine_Learning/Text_Analysis/Ontology_based.py` is directly working in your CMD shell because it can locate the `python` executable using the `PATH` variable. Please provide the absolute path to `python` command in your Java code. In below code replace `<Absolute Path to Python>` with the path to `python` command and its libraries. Usually it will something like `C:\Python27\python` in Windows by default

```
package text_clustering;

import java.io.*;

public class Similarity {

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            String pythonPath = "C:/Machine_Learning/Text_Analysis/Ontology_based.py";
            //String pythonExe = "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda/python.exe";
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("<Absolute Path to Python>/python", pythonPath));
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            System.out.println("Running Python starts: " + line);
            int exitCode = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exit Code : "+exitCode);
            line = bfr.readLine();
            System.out.println("First Line: " + line);
            while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Python Output: " + line);


            }

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading from stdin returns null when the script is killed/dies. Do a Process#waitFor and see what the `exitValue` is. If it isn't 0 then it's highly probable that your script is dying.

I'd try making it work with a dumb script that only writes a value. Make sure that you print all error information from python.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "python   D://input.py   ");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()));

    String line;  
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            System.out.println(line);  
        }  
        in.close();
        p.waitFor();



} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Python27/python", "D://searchTestJava//input.py");
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println(".........start   process.........");
    String line = "";
    while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Python Output: " + line);
    }

    System.out.println("........end   process.......");

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: A little explanation of what your code does wouldn't be bad.

Comment: This helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this](https://interviewbubble.com/how-to-execute-a-python-file-with-arguments-in-java) one. This script runs a python file with the argument in Java. It also logs about which line, your program is executing. Hope this Helps.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.Reader;

    public class Test {
      public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder pb =
                new ProcessBuilder("python","samples/test/table_cv.py","1.pdf");

        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process proc = pb.start();

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String s;
        while ((s = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
  }
```