# Java ProcessBuilder waitfor () never competing

Tags: java

Below is my code.Trying to execute python script but waitfor() never completing . Below is my code. Any suggestions.

```
String[] command ={"CMD","C:\\Users\\vkode200\\IdeaProjects\\Pythonex1\\TestHello.py"}; 

         ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command );
            //You can set up your work directory
            /*probuilder.directory(new File("c:\\xyzwsdemo"));*/

            Process process = probuilder.start();

            //Read out dir output
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n",
                    Arrays.toString(command));
            /*while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
*/
            //Wait to get exit value
            try {
                 exitValue = process.waitFor();
                 /*exitValue= process.exitValue();*/
                System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: *Wait to get exit value* - maybe still alive? check `ps`

Comment: I think you should use python to execute your script and not CMD. [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171862/java-processbuilder-not-able-to-run-python-script-in-java)

Comment: Thanks ZeusNet i followed what you said and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the process's input stream, and consume all its output on both `stdout` and `stderr`, before calling `waitFor()`.

Otherwise it can be blocked trying to read input you aren't sending, or produce output you aren't reading.

Comment: Thanks EJP i have closed input stream and  also followed ZeusNet suggestion to include python Python instead of cmd  and its worked for me.